# Show HTML DIV between two other DIVs

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid-layout

I have build with SO help a HTML CSS Grid/Flexbox compbined Layout with quite progress. But now i have a problem with showing an additionall div named class `mobile_nav`.

It should be activated when the user clicks on `SWITCH` (i can google this, therefore not part of question) and been displayed between DIV `<div class="section site-menu">` and DIV `<div class="section site-header">` (this is what i want and which is not working). So better call it as mobile navigation.

Can someone see whats wrong with it?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/ybog/pen/WZwdaM)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.site-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.site-menu {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  /* padding: 8px 20px 9px; */
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.hero {
  background-image: url('https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/landscape-mountains-nature-clouds.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100wh;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.hero-content {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  flex-directon: column;
  margin: auto;
}

.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: -1.2em;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

#nav,
#left_side,
#top_nav,
#bottom_nav {
  display: flex;
}

#nav {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}

#title {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#menu_switch {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#left_side {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

#top_nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  align-items: center;
}

.left {
  margin-right: auto;
}

#bottom_nav {
  align-items: center;
  height: 38px;
}

.nav_item {
  padding: 5px;
}

.nav_item:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#logo {
  background-color: black;
  margin-left: 24px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="section site-menu">
    <div id="nav">
      <div id="logo">
        100x100px Logo
      </div>
      <div id="left_side">
        <div id="top_nav">
          <div id="title" class="nav_item left">TITLE OF PAGE</div>
          <div id="menu_about" class="nav_item right">ABOUT</div>
          <div id="menu_signup" class="nav_item right">SIGN UP</div>
          <div id="menu_follow" class="right nav_item">FOLLOW</div>
          <div id="menu_switch" class="right nav_item">SWITCH</div>
        </div>
        <div id="bottom_nav">
          <div class="nav_item">AZURE</div>
          <div class="nav_item">SHAREPOINT</div>
          <div class="nav_item">BI & DWH</div>
          <div class="nav_item">.NET DEVELOPMENT</div>
          <div class="nav_item">MOBILE DEVELOPMENT</div>
          <div class="nav_item">WORDPRESS</div>
          <div class="nav_item">NOTES</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section mobile_nav">
    <div>dlfdh afj hdslf</div>
    <div>bla bla bla</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section site-header">
    <div class="hero">
      <div class="hero-content">
        <h1>If you can dream it, you can do it...</h1>
        <p class="subhead">lets do it !</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-right">
      <span>This text should be positioned at the bottom right of the Hero Image</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section undefined">
    <div class="undefined-content">
      <p>Lots of content will go in here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section site-footer">Footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your `mobile_nav` div is below your `site-menu` div. Just set `z-index` to `2` and you'll see your text. Also, if you want to 'activate' some elements dynamically, you might want to use JavaScript or media queries at least (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: In general yes, when i set to `z-index:2` i can see the text. But its placed over the navigation. I want to have it between the navigation and the hero image.

Comment: Well there you go, you just need to set the `position` attribute of `.site-menu` to `relative`

Comment: So simple? It works, thank you. Please post this one as answer and i will mark it as accepted answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put your `.site-menu` div position to relative.

It was set to absolute so not in the relative hierarchy.

Have a look at this page about the `position` attribute, https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp it's really well explained

**EDIT**

Actually you can just remove the position attribute. The position is `static` if you specify nothing so the items will be positioned one below the other.
Another link that could be useful for you : [CSS Display](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp)

Comment: But why is this the case? I mean all the other divs are also among themselves and there was no need for `position:relative`!? There must be something different.

Comment: Please dont misunderstand me but when you look at my Fiddle @Codepen, then you will see that without position:relative this one single div will not be position between the others. But the others dont even need the position. Why?

Comment: You did not remove the `position` attribute. I can see `position: absolute` there. Obviously, as explained in the article I provided, if you specify `position: absolute`, the div won't be in the same flow anymore. Just remove `position: absolute`

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail. Its important for me to not only copy and paste some code/snippet instead to understand what happens why.